# Show M2M read only in opposite side

Tags: django, admin

Let's say i have these two models:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
   event = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, null=True)

class Event(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
   long_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to show a list of assigned objects in the opposite side of the relation (Event)

Let's say i enter to edit a Event .. i want to display in a read only ul list of the Actors assigned.

I think it should not be a form widget.. but a straight html tag.

Comment: try event.actor.all in template . that will give you all the actors

Comment: im sorry but what template? i'm kind of starting with admin customization